# Convert nullable variable with int.parse using dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Do I need to convert a string? to an int if the value in the string is not null. (My routeArgs variable may be is null) I was doing according to this code before the null safety:

```
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
if(routeArgs["id"] != null){
   id = int.parse(routeArgs["id"]);
 }
```

But now it displays the error stating: "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'."  I tried to correct as the code below:

```
    final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
   
    int id;
    String? idtest = routeArgs["id"]; 
    if (idtest != null){
      id = int.parse(idtest);
    }
```

This code stopped giving error, but I think this is not the correct way to solve it, I would need to do this for several variable values. Would it be correct for me to make a function just for conversion? Could anyone give me an idea of a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```dart
> final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
>
> int id;
> String? idtest = routeArgs["id"];
> if (idtest != null){
>   id = int.parse(idtest);
> }
> ```

The above isn't quite right because `id` is not declared to be nullable nor is it declared to be `late`, and since not all code paths initialize `id`, you will get a compilation error if you attempt to actually use `id`.

Aside from that, adding local variables to allow automatic type-promotion to occur is usually the right thing to do.  However, in this case, depending on exactly what you want, you perhaps could be more succinct if you don't mind being slightly less efficient:

```dart
int? id = int.tryParse(routeArgs['id'] ?? '');
```

or if you want `id` to have some non-`null` default value:

```dart
int id = int.parse(routeArgs['id'] ?? '0');
```

Note that the first version has different behavior from your original code: if `routeArgs['id']` is an unparseable `String`, `null` will be assigned to `id` instead of throwing a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

Performing type checking is the best way, this also goes for modalroute args.

```
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;

int id;
var idtest = routeArgs["id"]; 
if (idtest is String){
  id = int.parse(idtest);
}
```

Check args ModalRoute:

```
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments
if(routeArgs is Map<String, String>){
  var id = 0;
  var idtest = routeArgs["id"]; 
  if (idtest is String){
    id = int.parse(idtest);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (idtest != null)` (which is what the OP is already doing) more clearly expresses the intent that you're checking for `null`.

Comment: [Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Cl0C-9dK48&ab_channel=Flutter)

Comment: I haven't watched the video, so I'm not sure what your point is, but `idtest != null` will type-promote `idtest` too since it's a local variable.  As the OP pointed out, `idtest != null` *works*; OP is looking for an approach that's less verbose.

Comment: My point is that  `if (idtest != null)`  is not a String, it can be dynamic, int, double, etc. Obviously the id inside the map is a string, but the best thing is to always state the result, basic in any test.

Comment: That's fair for the second version, but the first version already assumes that `routeArgs` is a `Map<String, String>`, and there will be a runtime exception beforehand if the values aren't actually `String`s.

Comment: Yes perfectly, that's why I talked about checking the type that MoldaRoute provides. And use the `is` operator instead of `as`, since the `is` is a question and the `as` is a statement.

Comment: But again, the `is String` checks provide *zero* advantage to `!= null` and instead make the intent less clear.  In both cases, there is no advantage because it's already statically provable (whether by the explicit `as Map<String, String>` cast from the first version or the `is Map<String, String>` check from the second) that `idtest` is either a `String` or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **sure** `routeArgs['id']` returns an string, you can do

```
final String idTest = routeArgs['id'];
```

Remember, with null-safety, if you are sure that some nullable value will not be null on a specific runtime, you can tell the compiler that with `!`.

For example

```
User? user; //Here the user variable is null
user = User(); 
user.id; // if you do this, the compiler will throw an error, because you want the id of the user, but the variable user could be null.
```

Here you have two options

1. `user?.id ?? 'guid'` // You provide a "default" value if the user variable is null
2. `user!.id`  // Here you ensure to the compiler that at this point, the variable user will **NOT** be null